# What temperature monitoring software is avalible for Server 2003, 2008 and 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, monitoring, physical-environment

I don't have much experience working with servers and I need to monitor temperatures for several servers (remotely). I use hwmonitor for my laptops but it doesn't support server hardware. Does anyone know of something that'll work?

Would love something that will send notifications when certain conditions/thresholds are met, but not necessary as I can remote connect to them and check periodically.

Comment: As the ability to even be able to get the temperature from the system will be system dependent it's worth mentioning the make and model of the servers, or at least the motherboards.

Answer (score 1):

I use Nagios, and it has plugins for all sort of services it can monitor. It also works with thresholds. 
Here is an example of a plugin that can monitor temperatures of a HP Proliant: [Check_hpasm](http://labs.consol.de/lang/de/nagios/check_hpasm/)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to monitoring a single server you can try with [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) or [RealTemp](http://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/) that work also on standard os, for monitoring server from a centralized consolle nagios or [solarwinds](http://www.solarwinds.com/) are more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

[eSensors](http://www.eesensors.net/) have small hardware devices that can monitor server room temperature.  Those devices can be monitored by Nagios, [PA Server Monitor](http://www.poweradmin.com/servermonitor) and others.

Answer (score 0):

This is speaking for HP servers, but I imagine other manufacturers will do a similar sort of thing.

When configured, the server can expose its thermal sensor information using SNMP. Amongst other things it will expose CPU temperatures, general ambient temperature, along with the thermal shutdown thresholds for each sensor. You can monitor and graph the current temperature and thermal shutdown values and set up alerts with your favourite monitoring software. Personally I use Nagios and Cacti to do this, but any half-decent monitoring software will allow you to do this with relative ease.

Additionally, the HP Insight Agents install services into Windows which can send you emails when all manner of events happen. This includes thermal alerts, but also things like dead hard disks, PSU's, fans so it's well worth spending 5 minutes configuring that (seriously, it's literally enter an email server, alert recipients and events to alert each recipient of and you're done).

Answer (score 0):

If you use APC UPS units, or others that have modules for networking and external sensors, that is a very nice way to go.

Comment: And how does the temperature sensor in a UPS tell you the temperature in a server?

Comment: It tells you the temp of the air next to the server, which is what we normally measure....